# Canon G1 X Custom Color Resets

Tags: canon, troubleshooting, canon-g1-x

The Canon Powershot G1 X has a *Custom Color* mode which lets you tweek Contrast, Saturation, Sharpness, Red, Green, Blue and Skin Tone. With a few adjustments, it can make colors look quite natural.

However, every once in a while, these settings strangely revert to their default values? Most of the time, the settings remain, even after power-cycling but several times I was surprised to see them reset. After trying several time to get them to reset as a result of some action (other than a camera reset of course), I cant get them to reset.

**Does anyone know when the G1 X resets Custom Color parameters?**

Comment: How about if you switch to RAW and back to JPEG? Just a guess.

Comment: The G1X Manual says that My Colors (which includes custom color) is unavailable in many shooting modes and when some features are used, have you been changing mode or using specific features around when you noticed the reset?

Comment: Yes, I've been using all sorts of features but I have not out which ones yet!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out that turning the dial to either C1 or C2 has its own memory for Custom Color. So, it needs to be set there too independently if desired. Once set in all 3 locations, Custom Color no longer resets.